# How to set permissions on items of filtered task list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Hello I'm starting to work with Sharepoint and found a problem I could not understand how to solve and need your help. 
I have a list of tasks that must be managed by a particular group. I prepared a page where to insert this filtered list of three ways: in the first frame only tasks not started, in the second frame only tasks in the development process and in the third frame tasks in approval. The problem: a certain group of users can edit a task, and another group can only edit some specific fields. How do I solve this problem?

Practical example: 
The project manager can create a task. 
The developer can open a task and change the status to "development", but can not change the task details. 
The developer can change the status of this task to "approval".

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In the most basic sense this can't be done--I mean setting permissions by field.  However, this can be done with two lists and connect them via workflows. So, in the first list give the managers full-control and create a workflow so that when they add a task it creates a new task in the developers' task list, which the developers have rights to. If you want to add the Task Description to the developers' list you can make it read-only on this list but writable on the managers' task list.  Then create a workflow on the developers' task list that updates the status of the task on the managers' task list when the child task is updated.

Update: I said give the managers full-control but this isn't necessary.  Contribute rights is sufficient on both lists just don't give the developers rights on the managers' list.